# Unity 2022 - Public Variables Showing as Dotted Grid in Inspector

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am a beginner in game dev and just started working in Unity. For some reason, the public variable in Visual Studio shows up as dotted grid in Unity element inspector instead of showing the value field… Even after clicking on it and typing anything does not alter this. Below is a screenshot of this:

[image]

Please help with this.

Comment: Id say its your pc, so it could be a driver, lack of spec many things. But, its not normal

Comment: Does CameraMovement have custom inspector?

Comment: @Nikaas nope there is no custom inspector… i switched to unity 2019 and its working fine…

Comment: So this is a problem of unity version compatibility